# How to know the values of $R$ and $L$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, linear-systems

Yo there! I have a RL circuit in the arrange showed in the image.

[image]

Ok, the trick is how can determine the values of the components based on the graphics of a step and impulse response, I detail the process and the graps in the images; basically what is done is to determine the model, calculate the unit and step response, got a 3 equations systems, but at the end, it is only a quotient, but aside that I don't see where can it get the values of R and L.
Thanks in advance

The graphs are double-checked, it seems odd but are ok.
1st , it gets the math model of the system

$$
i(t){\displaystyle \frac{R_{1}}{L}={\displaystyle \frac{dI_{L}}{dt}+({\displaystyle \frac{R_{2}+R_{1}}{L})I_{L}}}}
$$

Calculating unit step and impulse response applying the input  $i(t)=10_{u}(t)[A]$

$$
I_{L}(t)={\displaystyle \frac{10R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{2}}(1)-{\displaystyle \frac{10R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{2}}e{\displaystyle \frac{-R_{1}+R_{2}}{L}t}}}
$$
and
$$
h(t)={\displaystyle \frac{10R_{1}}{L}e{\displaystyle \frac{-R_{1}+R_{2}}{L}t}}
$$
In the step graph it says  $I(t)$ but there is trouble trying to fit the data, perhaps it should say  $I_{L}(t)$, taking the graph this way:
From the step graph
$$
{\displaystyle \frac{10R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{2}}=5...[1a]}
$$
and
$$
{\displaystyle \frac{10R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{2}}(1-e^{-{\displaystyle \frac{R_{1}+R_{2}}{L}(5\mu s)}})=4.325...[2a]}
$$
1a in 2a
$$
4.325=5(1-e^{-{\displaystyle \frac{R_{1}+R_{2}}{L}(5\mu s)}})...[3a]
$$
from the impulse
$$
68000={\displaystyle \frac{5R_{1}}{L}e^{{\displaystyle \frac{-R_{1}+R_{2}}{L}(2.5\mu s)}}...[4a]}
$$
from [3a]
$$
{\displaystyle \frac{4.325}{5}=(1-e^{-{\displaystyle \frac{R_{1}+R_{2}}{L}(5\mu s)}})...[5a]}
$$
Grouping terms and aplying the natural log
$$
ln(e^{-{\displaystyle \frac{R_{1}+R_{2}}{L}(5\mu s)}})=ln(1-{\displaystyle \frac{4.325}{5})...[5b]}
$$

$$
{\displaystyle \frac{R_{1}+R_{2}}{L}={\displaystyle \frac{-2.0024}{-5\mu}=400,490...[5c]}}
$$
From 1a
$$
10R_{1}=5(R_{1}+R_{2})...[6a]5R_{1}=5R_{2}...[6b]R_{1}=R_{2}...[6c]
$$
from  6c in 5c 
$$
{\displaystyle \frac{2R}{L}=400,490}
$$
$$
{\displaystyle \frac{R}{L}=200,245...[7a]}
$$

This one is where it gets stalled because I don't see where to tackle the values,

Comment: Yo yourself : ), I added in the image because users normally like to read without going off site.   Personally, I think this is an ElectronicsSE kind of question,  but the best of luck with it.

Comment: Thanks  CountTo10, It was my idea to add the picture, but the editing form says I cannot insert directly images. Thanks a lot again.